# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an observer for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

It all works, except it works when the viewController is not currently visible.

I've tried comparing to `self.navigationcontroller.topViewController` but this doesn't work when I have a modal view presented as the `topViewController` is the one underneath the modal view controller.

Comment: If the view controller isn't visible, why would you want to observe events?

Comment: Hmm... I suppose I could add the listener in viewWillAppear and remove in viewWillDisappear. Does viewWillDisappear get called when you present a modal view controller?

Comment: yes. Usually you keep observers running only as much as needed.

Comment: Thanks both. If you'd like to make an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `UIViewController` you could register your instance for Keyboard Notifications when the view becomes visible inside `viewWillAppear:` and then de-register when the view gets hidden inside `viewWillDisappear:`
This way you won't receive notifications when the view is not visible.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That answer doesn't work when the top view is a modal. Because parent's viewWillDisappear will not be called.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to react to that notification when the viewController is visible, then just check if is visible at the beginning of the function:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([self.view window]) //means is visible
        //do something
    else 
        //return
}
```

Comment: +1 as I didn't know about the `[self.view window]` function. Used a different solution though. Thanks

Comment: Great, is also true that is a good convention remove the observer when not needed.

Comment: Using `self.view` has the side effect that the view is loaded if it hasn't been already. You should check `isViewLoaded` before.

Comment: Thats true, but he is checking for a view that is already visible, so there is no way it is not loaded